# Magento 2 : Which File & Line app/etc/di.xml Config Will Load by App

Tags: magento2, di, architecture, file

I need to know, area wise config will load by application entry point files like `/Magento/Framework/App/Http` launch method.

But I'm not able to figure it out `app/etc/di.xml` config load.

Comment: @SivaKumarKoduru If you have additional questions, write them to me in comments, I will try to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**File**: `vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php`

**Line**: 259 , method: `_loadPrimaryConfig`

Here the primary config (`app/etc/di.xml`) is loaded first time:

[image: screenshot]

All another `di.xml` was loaded in the:

1. For the developer mode: `Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer::configureObjectManager()`
2. For the production mode: `Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Compiled::configureObjectManager()`

by calling the:

```
$objectManager->configure(
    $objectManager
        ->get('Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ConfigLoaderInterface')
        ->load(Area::AREA_GLOBAL)
);
```

which loads instance of the `Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader` and loads the config files in the `load()` method dynamically or from the cache (if enabled):

```
/**
 * {inheritdoc}
 */
public function load($area)
{
    $cacheId = $area . '::DiConfig';
    $data = $this->_cache->load($cacheId);

    if (!$data) {
        $data = $this->_getReader()->read($area);
        $this->_cache->save(serialize($data), $cacheId);
    } else {
        $data = unserialize($data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Result in the debug looks like this:

[image: result in the debug]

Then the result merges in the `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager::configure()` method with initial config (`app/etc/di.xml`).  All data are stored in the config attribute (`$this->_config`) of the `ObjectManager`.

Comment: Thank u what about modules di.xml

Comment: @sivakumar I improved the answer and added the information about the another scope configuration. I hope it will be useful for you.